# Error where no default constructor exists for a class

Tags: c++, c++11, tokenize

I'm working on a program that is supposed to parse a command-line input, read an input text file, and then execute the sequence of steps specified from the test file.

After working on the tokenizer class for some time, I've hit a wall, namely an error, that I'm not really sure how to solve.

So, I have Tokenizer.h:

```
#ifndef _TOKENIZER_GUARD
#define _TOKENIZER_GUARD 1
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Token.h"

//
// A class to create a sequence of tokens from an input file stream.
//
class Tokenizer
{
    public:
        Tokenizer(const std::string&, std::ostream&);
        Tokenizer(Tokenizer&); // Copy Constructor -I
        virtual ~Tokenizer();

        virtual int nextInt();
        virtual bool hasNextInt() const;
        virtual long nextLongInt();
        virtual bool hasNextLongInt() const;
        virtual float nextFloat();
        virtual bool hasNextFloat() const;
        virtual std::string next();
        virtual bool hasNext() const;
        Tokenizer& operator= (Tokenizer&); // overloaded equals operator

    protected:

    private:
        Tokenizer();
        std::ifstream stream;
        std::ostream _os;
        Token _token;
};

#endif
```

And Tokenizer.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Tokenizer.h"

Tokenizer::Tokenizer()
{    //error occurs here

}
// Constructor 
Tokenizer::Tokenizer(const std::string& s, std::ostream& o)
{   //error occurs here
    stream.open(s);
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
}


// Copy Constructor 
Tokenizer::Tokenizer(Tokenizer& t) :_token(t._token), stream(t.stream), _os(t._os)
{

}


// Destructor
Tokenizer::~Tokenizer()
{
     stream.close();
}

// Saves current int to return, then moves _token to the next value 
int Tokenizer::nextInt()
{
    int temp = _token.toInteger();
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
    return temp;
}

// Checks to see if there is a next value and if it is an int
bool Tokenizer::hasNextInt() const
{
    return _token.isInteger() && hasNext();
}

// same as nextInt but long -I
long Tokenizer::nextLongInt()
{
    long temp = _token.toLongInteger();
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
    return temp;
}

// same as hasNextInt but Long 
bool Tokenizer::hasNextLongInt() const
{
    return _token.isLongInteger() && hasNext();
}

// same as nextInt but Float 
float Tokenizer::nextFloat()
{
    float temp = _token.toFloat();
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
    return temp;
}

// same as hasNextInt but float 
bool Tokenizer::hasNextFloat() const
{
    return _token.isFloat() && hasNext();
}

//Returns the next token 
std::string Tokenizer::next()
{
    std::string temp = _token.get();
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
    return temp;
}

//True when it is not the end of the file
bool Tokenizer::hasNext() const
{
    return stream.eofbit != 1;
}

//Overloaded = operator 
Tokenizer& Tokenizer::operator= (Tokenizer& t)
{
    _token = t._token;
    stream = t.stream;
    _os = t._os; //error occurs here
}
```

I get the error

> 'std::basic_ostream>': no appropriate default >constructor available

for the constructor. Later, when I use 'stream = t.stream' and '_os = t._os' I get the error

> function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator=(const >std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, >_Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 85 of >"x:\Visual\VC\include\ostream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted >function

I've been trying to find some sort of solution for the first error, but I don't understand what's causing it. Creating a copy constructor was suggested to me, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. I've also included Token.h below.

```
#ifndef _TOKEN_GUARD
#define _TOKEN_GUARD 1

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>

//
// Token class
//
class Token
{
public:
    Token(const std::string& t) : _token(t) { }

    virtual std::string get() const { return _token; }

    virtual long toLongInteger() const;
    virtual bool isLongInteger() const;
    virtual int toInteger() const;  // for int and is int functions
    virtual bool isInteger() const; //
    virtual float toFloat() const;
    virtual bool isFloat() const;
    virtual bool isNonNumeric() const;
    Token() : _token("") {}
    std::string _token;
protected:

};

#endif
```

I apologize in advance if I'm being too vague or something along those lines. I'm more than happy to provide anything else needed (since I'm stuck at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error message is very clear. When you use:

```
Tokenizer::Tokenizer(const std::string& s, std::ostream& o)
{   //error occurs here
    stream.open(s);
    std::string t;
    getline(stream, t, ' ');
    _token = Token(t);
}
```

the member variable `os_` is default constructed. Since there is no default constructor in `std::ostream`, `os_` cannot be initialized.

I am guessing that you mean to initialize the member variable `os_` with the input argument to the constructor of `Tokenizer`, like:

```
Tokenizer::Tokenizer(const std::string& s, std::ostream& o) : os_(o) 
{
   ...
```

Even that won't work since `std::ostream` does not have a copy constructor. You'll need to change the member variable to a reference object.

```
std::ostream& os_;
```

Then, you can safely use:

```
Tokenizer::Tokenizer(const std::string& s, std::ostream& o) : os_(o) 
{
   ...
```

You just have to make sure that the input argument, `o`, is not destroyed before the `Tokenizer` is destroyed. Otherwise, the `Tokenizer` object will be left with a dangling reference.

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble with having the input argument destroyed before Tokenizer is (Thank you for clearing up the constructor), which is still ending up in a lot of attempts to reference the deleted function. For example, when the copy constructor attempts to reference it, I get:
    

>function "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const           std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char,     _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 825 of "x:\Visual\VC\include\fstream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Comment: _basic_ifstream_ has deleted copy constructor ([basic_ifstream constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)), thus you cannot copy it as intended. You should use different approach, like keeping stream pointer or creating brand new stream object in the copy constructor.