# Why does using a reference member prevent deleted constructor errors?

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor, default-constructor

#### Context

I have two classes (simplified to the relevant declarations):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Lexer
{
    std::ifstream file_;
    Lexer(std::string &file) : file_(file){};
};

class Parser
{
    Lexer lexer_;
    Parser(Lexer &lex) : lexer_(lex){};
};
```

This fails to compile with the error

> error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]'

After eventually finding [Error where no default constructor exists for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307756/error-where-no-default-constructor-exists-for-a-class) I think I now understand:

- The issue is that `ifstream` has a deleted default constructor which prevents `Lexer` from being used in `Parser` because it's not being supplied a string (whereas the `Lexer` class itself compiles fine).
- If I make `Lexer` take an `ifstream` directly there's still an error (similar reasoning as above) because it also has a deleted copy constructor.
- By making `file_` a reference member (i.e. `std::ifstream &file_;`) the lack of copy constructor problem is solved because the member initialiser is no longer attempting to use a copy constructor (since it's just a reference).

---

**My questions are:**

1. Is my understanding correct? It feels a little fuzzy, but I'm new to C++ and still getting used to thinking about the use of reference in different contexts (I understand the general concept).
2. Why exactly is the lack of a default constructor an issue here, but not when just the `Lexer` class (as is above) is declared?
3. Is the use of a reference member the most semantically correct solution here?

Comment: Because a reference doesn't need to be copy constructed?

Comment: The fact that `ifstream` is noncopyable means that the `Lexer` is noncopyable

Comment: Copying a `Lexer` requires the contained `ifstream` OBJECT to be copied.   Copying an `ifstream` is not allowed   (since, logically, it would mean an end result of two distinct objects that each manage distinct flows of data from the same physical file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifstream` does have a default constructor. The error you pasted it because of the deleted copy constructor. The code you wrote will not work, because `Lexer` can not be copy constructed with the default, because `ifstream` is not copyable.

So, to answer you questions:

1. Your understanding is incorrect; though not a bad guess.
2. Not related to default constructor.
3. Depends what you are trying to do. You may want to prevent copying of Lexer, or make your own copy constructor, or use references.

Comment: Thank you, this nicely answers my question as written and I suppose what my real source of confusion was too (it just clicked for me that the implicit copy constructor must also copy constructs the members). Knowing the lack of copy constructor is the issue also clarifies why it only became a problem once used in the Parser.